# Software updater changes permissions for some files in /var/lib/apt/lists/

Tags: 20.04, update-manager

On Ubuntu 20.04. The software updater (or something before that) changes the permissions on the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`. For example:

```
...
-rw------- 1 _apt root  24K  8月 28 16:24 packagecloud.io_rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116K  8月 28 16:23 packagecloud.io_rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116K  8月 28 16:23 packagecloud.io_rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-i386_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11K  9月  1 21:17 packages.microsoft.com_repos_code_dists_stable_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 288K  9月  1 12:54 packages.microsoft.com_repos_code_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
...
```

The software updater fails saying that it has no permission for the file `packagecloud.io_rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease`.

By the way, a few hours ago the permissions on the file `packagecloud.io_rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease` was `-rw-r--r--` (and the ownership on `root:root`)

There are two options to fix that:

- `chmod 644 packagecloud.io_rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease`
- `sudo apt update` (that fixes the permissions as well)

But whenever the software updater makes a check, some of the files' permissions get changed and the software updater fails. Is there a permanent remedy for that?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using ? You tag your question with 20,04, but show bionic sources, bionic is 18.04 --- sources from mixed releases is bound to give problems. Please fix this.

Comment: I am using `20.04`. I could double check that. However, it also happened to other files like `security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease`